# unable to pass multiple inputs in sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have a very basic question/issue.

I want to the swal.mixin function. I want my user to upload 2 Images and one text...

Now... I have successfully added Ajax. My problem is, that it will not add the pictures to my database. Does anyone know if I made a mistake in the code?

This is the server I run on : https://mars.iuk.hdm-stuttgart.de/~mk304/Web_Projekt/webpage/ui/sweetalert/sweetalert_eingabe.php

```html
<script>
    var kuerzeltest = "mk304";
    var channeltest = "3";

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#new-btn').click(function () {

            swal.mixin({
                input: 'text',
                confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
                showCancelButton: true,
                progressSteps: ['1', '2', '3']
            }).queue([
                {
                    input: 'file',
                    title: 'Profilbild hochladen',
                    text: 'Empfohlen wird 1X1'
                },
                {
                    input: 'file',
                    title: 'Hintergrundbild hochladen',
                    text: 'Empfohlen wird 16X9'
                },
                {

                    title: 'Über mich',
                    text: ''
                },

            ]).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {

                    var bild = result.value[0];
                    var bild2 = result.value[1];
                    var post = result.value[2];

                    $.ajax({ type: "POST",  url: "../../register/profil_update.php",
                        data: {"post":result.value[2],"bild":result.value[0], "kuerzel": kuerzeltest },

                    });
                    swal(
                        "Super!",
                        "Dein Profil wurde erfolgreich aktualisiert ",
                        "success"

                    )
                }
            })
        });
    })


</script>
```

Thanks so much for your help, I have been searching for hours....

my backend code:

```html
<?php
include_once '../../userdata.php';
//Posts in Datenbank schreiben


$kuerzel = $_SESSION["kuerzel"];
$bild = $_POST["bild"];
$bild2 = $_POST["bild2"];
$post = $_POST["post"];

$pdo = new PDO ($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, array('charset'=>'utf8'));
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_bilder (kuerzel, bild, bild2, post) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute(array("$kuerzel", "$bild", "$bild2", "$post"));

$row = $statement->fetchObject();

header("Location: ../home/home.php");

?>
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, your problem is on the backend. Your frontend code look ok (apart from the fact that you show success swal without waiting for the response to the AJAX call). You should have a look to the backend code and check if the POST data is correctly received

Comment: hi, thank you so much for the reply, I added my backend (Upload to the server) but it still doesn't work. Can you see why..?

Comment: Looking better at your front-end code I've actually saw a problem with the way you are using swal. You are using `result[i]` but result is not an array. The correct array is `result.value[]`. So first of all you need to replace those 2 lines. Then, result.value[0] and result.value[1] returns file handlers that you can use accordingly to (for example) this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Comment: hey @G.Verni, thank you so much, that really helped me a lot. I got it to post the text into my database, but I am struggling with the file handlers (sorry I am super new to javascript...). What do I need to do to in order to add the images to my database? I updated my Script, to where I am at the moment, thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: @G.Verni, I started a new question (so that its more detailed) here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53240263/how-do-i-use-file-handlers-in-sweetalert